# How to use Filesystem.readFile if I have a full path

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic4, capacitor

In an Capacitor/Ionic/Angular app I am trying to allow a user to take a video, view it in a `<video>` tag, and I also need to be able to send the video data in a POST request when the user submits it.

I'm getting the video using Cordova's MediaCapture plugin so what I get back contains a `fullPath` of the form `file://`...

The bit I'm stuck on is then actually getting a File/Blob object from the full path.

I tried using `Filesystem.readFile()` from Capacitor Plugins, but the problem is that it requires a `path: string` and a `directory: FilesystemDirectory`. If I try to just provide `{path: fullPath}` I get a "File does not exist" error. The FilesystemDirectory just gives me several options to choose from but I wouldn't want to use it as I already have the full path and don't want to go into checking which directory I should use in which device.

Is there any other way I can get around this?

Comment: hey, I am facing the same issue? Have you solved it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `Capacitor.convertFileSrc('file:///path/to/video.mp4');`, then you'll have a path that the webview understands and you can use fetch/xhr to that path to get the `Blob`. (Note that on iOS it won't work if running in live reload mode as iOS blocks requests from http scheme (used by the live reload server) to capacitor scheme (regular capacitor scheme when running normally)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I tried Capacitor.convertFileSrc and it worked well in live reload but when I build production apk it's giving me 404 error while fetch using http.get(). Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.